# ¿Cómo encontrar el elemento mínimo y el elemento máximo en una lista de lista?

Tags: python, array, lista

Es decir, tengo por ejemplo la lista de abajo y que el mínimo es 0 y el máximo es 8, pero ¿como los encuentro?

```
M=[[1,2,3],[0,3,4],[3,7,8]]
```

Se que si fuera una sola lista sin listas dentro, este es el código:

```
maximo = M[0]
minimo = M[0]
 for i in M:    
     if i > maximo:
             maximo = i
     if i < minimo:
             minimo = i
print maximo
print minimo
```

Pero esto no funciona si los elementos de la lista son listas.

Comment: Hola Adolfo, ¿es una tarea en la que estés limitado a usar ciclos o algo así? Si es así, la idea es la misma pero debes ierar sobre cada sublista usando un for anidado simplemente ¿O puedes usar cualquier cosa que ponga a disposición el el lenguaje? Lo digo porque puedes usar los built-ins `min` y `max` junto a un generador o `map`...

Comment: Hola, pues no estoy limitado a usar ciclos, pero no se usar los built-ins min y max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como estas usando sublistas, tenes que crear un ciclo `for:` para entrar en cada lista, el primer ciclo entra en `[[1,2,3],[0,3,4],[3,7,8]]` y el segundo ciclo entra en cada lista `[1,2,3]` `[0,3,4]` y `[3,7,8]`, y utiliza el mismo codigo para determinar los valores Maximo y Minimo

```python
M = [[1,2,3],[0,3,4],[3,7,8]]

maximo = 0
minimo = 0
for i in M:    
    for j in i:
        if j > maximo:
            maximo = j
        if j < minimo:
            minimo = j
print maximo
print minimo
```

tambien puedes usar el modulo Numpy:

```python
import numpy as np
M = [[1,2,3],[0,3,4],[3,7,8]]

print np.min(M)
print np.max(M)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no se como no lo veía, pero tienes razón, si me sirvió, y lo de el modulo Numpy no se como es pero gracias también, lo voy a probar

Comment: Hola Lucas, ten en cuenta que si defines mínimo y máximo como 0 inicialmente el código fallará si existen valores negativos en la lista, si el valor mínimo de la misma es mayor de 0 o si todos los valores son menores de 0.

Answer (score 4):

Lo más eficiente generalmente y simple usando Python estándar (fuera de bibliotecas especializadas como NumPy) es usar los builtins `sum` y `min`, tienes varias posibilidades:

- Junto a expresión generadora:

  ```
  M = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 4], [3, 7, 8]]
  minimo = min(min(row for row in M))  
  maximo = max(max(row for row in M))
  ```
- Usando `map` (aproximación funcional):

  ```
  M = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 4], [3, 7, 8]]
  minimo = min(map(min, M))
  maximo = max(map(max, M))
  ```
- Usando `itertool.chain.from_iterable` para aplanar la lista:

  ```
  import itertools

  M = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 4], [3, 7, 8]]
  minimo = min(itertools.chain.from_iterable(M))
  maximo = max(itertools.chain.from_iterable(M))
  ```

Sin usar `min`/`max` puedes usar exactamente la misma idea que planteas en tu código para una lista pero usando un for extra para iterar sobre las sublistas:

```
M = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 4], [3, 7, 8]]

minimo = float("inf")
maximo = float("-inf")

for row in M:
    for item in row:
        if item < minimo:
            minimo = item
        if item > maximo:
            maximo = item
```

Si evaluamos el tiempo de ejecución para una lista de 30000 filas de 3 elementos por ejemplo, en mi caso obtengo:

> **# min/max y generador**
>   4.02 ms ± 115 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
> **# min/max e itertools.chain.from_iterable**
>   6.39 ms ± 42.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
> **# min/max y map**
>   11.4 ms ± 278 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
> **# Ciclos `for` anidados, variables y condicional**
>   7.58 ms ± 187 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

En este caso `min`/`max` y la expresión generadora es la más eficiente. `map` en este caso parece fracasar estrepitosamente....